# Haskell como transformar una lista Char en una Matriz?

Tags: funciones, haskell

Mi objetivo es el siguente:

A mi me pasan una lista de Char, por ejemplo:

```
["++++.++++.++."]
```

Lo que quiero lograr es separar esa lista en pequeñas listas (armar una matriz) de numeros Enteros, donde cada numero positivo representara la sumatorio de '+' y el numero negativo -1 el '.'

Siguendo el ejemplo de la lista que di, la matriz deberia ser asi:

```
[[4],[-1],[4],[-1],[2],[-1]]
```

*Uso GHCi, version 8.2.1*

Por ahora tengo:

```
compararChar :: (Char, Char) -> Bool
compararChar (c1, c2) = if c1==c2 then True else False

contarCaracteresHastaElPunto :: [Char] -> Int
contarCaracteresHastaElPunto [] = 0
contarCaracteresHastaElPunto (x:y) = if (compararChar(x, '.') /= True) then 1 + contarCaracteresHastaElPunto(y) else contarCaracteresHastaElPunto(y)
-- *Main> contarCaracteresHastaElPunto ("+++..")
-- 3
```

La funcion **contarCaracteresHastaElPunto** la hice para ver si me devolvia por lo menos la primer sumatoria de '+' hasta encontrar el primer punto '.'

Pero lamentablemente ni eso me salio bien. Ya que si le paso:

("+++..") me devuelve el numero 3, esta bien eso, pero si le paso por ejemplo ("+++.++"), me devolvera 5, o sea que suma todos los caracteres de la cadena en vez de sumar primeros 3.

Calculo que el problema esta en el `else` del `if`, pero no se como dejarlo vacio.

Si algun guru de haskell me puede dar una mano con todo este mambo, estaria muy agradecido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El módulo Data.List dispone de la función `group`, que recibe una lista de elementos comparables y devuelve una lista de listas donde cada sublista del resultado contiene únicamente elementos iguales:

```
Data.List> group "+++.++.+."
["+++",".","++",".","+","."]
```

Dada una sublista (que va a contener únicamente `+` o `.`) debemos devolver:

- una lista que contenga una única sublista indicando el número de `+` de la subcadena,
- o una lista que contenga una sublista `[-1]` por cada `.`,

para lo que creamos la siguiente función auxiliar:

```
g :: String -> [[Int]]
g xs@('.':_) = replicate (length xs) [-1]
g xs = [[length xs]]
```

Finalmente, creamos la función que agrupa los caracteres en sublistas (`group`), mapea cada lista con la función auxiliar `g` (`map g`) y concatena todas las listas (`concat`):

```
import Data.List(group)

f :: String -> [[Int]]
f = concat . (map g) . group
```

Por ejemplo:

```
ghci> f "+++.++.+."
[[3],[-1],[2],[-1],[1],[-1]]
```